# Why am I sending duplicates of one file in email?

Tags: java, file, email, directory

I have 2 files in the directory "bar" for testing. from the code below, it is suppose to send all files in that directory as email attachments. The problem is that when I send them, I get duplicates of one file in my email. I did have it working correctly once before for testing, but I dont remember what I might have changed.

Does anyone recognize what might be wrong with my code or why I instead of sending all the files in the directory, I get one file multiple times in my email?

Here is my code:

```
        multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        File f = new File("C:\\foo\\bar");
        File[] attachments = f.listFiles();

         //email with attachments (if any)
        for(int i = 0; i < f.listFiles().length - 1; i++){
            DataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(attachments[i]);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachments[i].getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            }

        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error: you want the loop to be either

```
for (int i = 0; i < f.listFiles().length; i++){
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= f.listFiles().length -1; i++){
```

You also have two lines that say

```
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

which is why you have the bodypart containing the first file twice.

Comment: Didn't catch that, thanks. But after removing the negative one and the duplicate, now it shows the last file twice... Any ideas? Anything that needs to be seen to shed some light?

Comment: There was another comment, now deleted, that noted that you don't create new messageBodyPart instances in the loop. You seem to be reusing the same messageBodyPart for all files, which means that on the first iteration of the loop, you are now setting the contents of that messageBodyPart to file1 and then on the second iteration, you are setting the contents to file2. It is added to the multipart twice and hence you have the last file twice. If there were 10 files, it would be the 10th file 10 times.

Comment: Just woke up. Ok I moved multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); outside of the loop. Now I just get the last file sent to my email once.

Comment: I figured it out. I actually did need a copy of the multi part. Here is the complete tutorial on showing it. Now I can send the files the correct way. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm